# A Leak in Apple's iPhone project template?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, xcode-template

Today, I tried to fix a leak in my newly created iPhone app. After some search, I've
discovered that Apple has a leak in it's Tab Bar application template. Have you discovered the same, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I remember people asking here about leaks where it turned out that the application only leaked in the simulator, not on the actual device. Can you observe the leak when running your app on an iPhone or iPod Touch? If it only occurs in the simulator, I wouldn't worry.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a new project from the template, make no alterations, and compile and run the project and find a leak, then [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

If you make alterations, then you need to determine if your changes caused the leak.